# Excel function to calculate pairwise date difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a excel sheet with all employees of my company. This list also includes the sick days of each employee. I want to calculate the sick days of each year.

My excel sheet looks like this (shortened version):

```
  A        B            C            D           E           F         G      ...
1 Name     From         To           From        To          From      To     ...
2 Max      2015/06/15   2015/06/16   2016/08/17  2016/08/17  
3 Sarah    2016/01/20   2016/01/20  
4 Phil 
...
```

Explanation: Max was sick for two times. First from 2015/06/15 to 2015/06/16 and second from 2016/08/17 to 2016/08/17. Every time he gets sick the table is expanded to the right. Sarah was sick only on 2016/01/20 and Phil wasn't sick.

Now, I want to calculate the sick days of a year.
I could do something like

```
   A      B
10 2015   Sum of sick days in 2015
11 2016   Sum of sick days in 2016
```

So what needs to be done is:

1. check if date is in the right year
2. pairwise calculation of networkdays of all dates in a row, that means 
   =SUM(NETWORKDAYS(B2;C2)) for 2015 and
   =SUM(NETWORKDAYS(D2;E2);NETWORKDAYS(B3;C3)) for 2016.

But it should work more dynamically. I only want to choose the matrix, e.g. A1 to I8 for each year and the rest should be calculated automatically. Does anybody know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below formula. (paste this in the cell B10

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR($B$2:$N$8)=$A10)*(MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$N$8),2)=0)*(($C$2:$O$8-$B$2:$N$8)+1))
```

Copy the above cell into B11. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems quite unruly:

```
=IF(YEAR(C2)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2))+IF(YEAR(G2)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(F2,G2))+IF(YEAR(K2)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(J2,K2))+IF(YEAR(C3)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(B3,C3))+IF(YEAR(G3)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(F3,G3))+IF(YEAR(K3)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(J3,K3))+IF(YEAR(C4)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(B4,C4))+IF(YEAR(G4)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(F4,G4))+IF(YEAR(K4)=A10,NETWORKDAYS(J4,K4))
```

Alternatively you could either write a macro to loop through the data *or* add an additional two columns in between each **From** and **To** column. D2 would be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",YEAR(C2))
```

and copy down. E2 would be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2))
```

and copy down. E11 would be

```
=SUMIF(D2:D4,$A11,E2:E4)
```

and copy across to I11 and M11 etc. You can then just

```
=SUM(C11:M11)
```

These new columns can be hidden if you needed.